# Is there a complete list of published dates for all the New 52 titles?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, timeline, justice-league

I didn't think I needed to ask this question, but DC forced me into this. I am not used to of DC's way of telling a story by putting it in several different comics and even in several different families. They are forcing us into reading everything they publish, even if I don't have any interest in few of the families at all. I tried reading few of the comic and they mix and merge with other families that I couldn't enjoy the story at all. Feeling like I was missing some part of it.

So I decided to read everything which is published under The New 52 Title. I bought some of the comics of most of the families starting from #1 of everything.  I am trying to buy everything which is unto a certain date. For example My first target is to read everything till 2012 and then till 2013 (I dunno if I'll ever reach in 2014 at all, considering there'll be more than thousand titles between these years).

Still I haven't really figured out which one to read first and which one to read next, so I've decided to read them in chronological order. I have got a pretty large collection till now (with the help of friends and bulk discount stores), but I do not want to miss anything.

So My question is, is there any way to know which comics have been released till a certain date, for example the list of comics published before January 2012 or the list of comics published in certain month for example in December 2011?

I am asking this so that I can read up in the order they were published so that I don't have to mess up with the actual story, trying to find missing piece of the puzzle.

PS: By the list of comics I mean every family or special edition they came up with. I am literally going to buy and read everything.

Comment: “They are forcing us into reading everything” — They’re not forcing you to do anything. If you’re not enjoying it, stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comics are released weekly, usually on Wednesdays.  The New 52 started waaay back on [August 31, 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52).  And it started in an off week.  Most months have 4 weeks, so comic book publishers aim for 4 weeks worth of releases.  August 31, 2011 however, was the [5th Wednesday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2011&month=8) of the month.  So, DC used this as a launching point.

On August 31, 2011, two comic books by DC were published, *Justice League #1* and *Flashpoint #5*.  This concluded *Flashpoint*, and began the New 52, which was a result of the *Flashpoint* event.  So, in terms of where to start, start there, with *Justice League #1*.

Then each week, they published roughly 13 comics (that's 52/4, they're releasing 52 comics a month).  So next step is to find each week's releases, which is fortunately really easy.  Googling 'comic book releases <date>' will get you plenty of news posts from various comic book sites.  I found [this handy site](http://www.comiclist.com/index.php/lists/comiclist-new-comic-book-releases-list-for-09-07-2011-beta) that lists each week's releases.  You can see there that on September 7, 2011 DC published 13 comics (some had variant covers), so you can buy and read all of them, then click the link at the top to get the list for September 14, and repeat.